# Why do we have to put components in the declarations array?

Tags: angular, typescript

We used to have to include Angular services in a `providers` array in the module definition. As Angular progressed, we now mainly use the `providedIn` property in the `@Injectable` decorator. The Angular compiler does a lot of nice stuff for us like tree shaking, so we just create the service, use `providedIn` and we're good to go.

I'm curious why the same thing can't be done for components. Currently, components need to be added to the `declarations` array in the module definition. The latest Angular is able to create dynamic components without `entryComponents` (create an ng factory on the fly), so shouldn't it be able to do the same type of thing it does for services with `providedIn`? Meaning that instead of having to put a component in the `declarations` array, it would do the same thing it does for services?

Comment: For services, you have to provide it in either NgModule using 'providers' or inside Injectable decorator you have to mention 'providedIn' to register the service. So similarly we have to declare components and @Component is only decorator to inform angular about the metadata.

Comment: what do you mean by `The latest Angular is able to create component factories on the fly`?

Comment: @micronyks Sorry, I meant entryComponents is no longer needed because Ivy will [load the ng factory imperatively](https://medium.com/@nishu0505/bye-bye-entrycomponents-a4cd933e8eaf).

Comment: @Tejeshree I think you misunderstood the question. I will update it to be more specific. providedIn obviously includes it in some sort of service registration that Angular uses. This means we *don't* have to include that service in the 'providers' array. Why can't the same thing be done with components? Why do the components need to be included in the 'declarations' array.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is done to know what component should be availed where. If all would be defined in root non of lazy loading would work. An other problem might be that there can be multiple directives/Components with the same selector. As such the compiler would have to guess what goes where.

Comment: You can define services in a module, such as `providedIn: MyModule`.

Comment: When asking for service be it’s class, you know exactly what you expect. There can’t be two services with same class (you can have collision in names but import will resolve it). For selector it is not possible, they are strings. And then the lazy loading, it is irrelevant where you declare your component if in module or in component definition, you still need to assign something.